# Is there an "efficient" injective mapping from $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algorithms, integers

Is there an "efficient" injective mapping $\psi$ from $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?
By this I mean:

1) there exists $K, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $|\psi( (a,b,c) )| \le max\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}^k+K$

2) there exists an algorithm $T$ or a Turing machine, such that there exists a $l \in \mathbb{N}$ and the time to compute $\psi((a,b,c))$ is bounded above by $max\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}^l$

Comment: The answer is "no" for the silly reason that all eight elements of $\{0,1\}^3$ would have to get mapped into $\{-1,0,1\}$. If you allow a constant in your inequality then what you're asking becomes possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. I will edit the question to allow a constant in the inequality

Comment: @MeesdeVries: How does it become possible? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the Cantor pairing function, $f(x,y)=\frac12 (x+y)(x+y+1)+x$, an obviously polynomial injection $\mathbb N^2\to\mathbb N$, and
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} -2x  & \text{when }x\le 0 \\ 2x-1 & \text{when } x > 0 \end{cases} $$
an obvously polynomial injection $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$.

Then define
$$ \psi(a,b,c) = f(f(g(a),g(b)),g(c)) $$

(With the above choice of $f$ and $g$, this is actually surjective onto $\mathbb N$ -- if you want a polynomially bounded *bijection* $\mathbb Z^3\to\mathbb Z$, just compose with the inverse of $g$).

(Also, the cost of computing these functions is polynomial in the number of *digits* in the inputs, not merely in their absolute size).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Write $\|v\|_\infty = \max\{|v_1|,|v_2|,|v_3|\}$. Let $\phi: \mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb N$ be *any* injection, computable in polynomial time, for which $\phi(0,0,0) = 0$, which induces an ordering $\leq$ on $\mathbb Z^3$. Now define a new ordering $\leq'$ on $\mathbb Z^3$ given by
$$
a \leq' b \iff (\|a\|_\infty < \|b\|_\infty) \lor (\|a\|_\infty = \|b\|_\infty \land a \leq b).
$$
The ordering $\leq'$ has order type of $\mathbb N$, and thus gives a bijection $\psi: \mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb N \subseteq \mathbb Z$. Furthermore, the only elements which can precede $\psi(a)$ under this bijections are those with norm below $a$, and there are only cubically many. To compute the value of a particular point in $\mathbb Z^3$, you therefore need to compute $\phi$ at most cubically many times. This gives a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to define psi?

Answer (score 1):

Partition ${\mathbb Z}^3$ in shells $$S_n:=\bigl\{(a,b,c)\in{\mathbb Z}^3\>|\>\max\bigl\{|a|,|b|,|c|\bigr\}=n\bigr\}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
Then $$|S_0|=1, \qquad|S_n|=24 n^2+2\quad(n\geq1)\ ,$$
and
$$a_{n-1}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|S_k|=2(n-1)(4n^2-2n+1)\ .$$ Devise a scheme  $\phi_n:\ S_n\to{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ (usable for all $n\geq1$) that counts the elements of $S_n$ in systematic way (a few lines of program code).

Put $\psi\bigl((0,0,0)\bigr):=0$. For $(a,b,c)\ne(0,0,0)$ let $n:=n(a,b,c):=\max\bigl\{|a|,|b|,|c|\bigr\}$, and put $$\psi(a,b,c):=a_{n-1}+\phi_n(a,b,c)\ .$$
In this way yu obtain a counting of ${\mathbb Z}^3$ that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As a "stupid" (and rather inefficient) but instructive alternative, you could also just write down "$a,b,c$" where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are represented in binary, encode the symbols in this representation as

```
0 - binary digit 0
1 - binary digit 1
2 - prefix minus for negative numbers
3 - comma
```

and then interpret the resulting sequence as a base-4 number.

If you represent numbers in binary, the cost of computing this is *linear* in the size of the inputs. The output contains up to $5$ non-digit symbols (two commas and up to three minus signs), so its *numeric* size is

$$ |\psi(a,b,c)| < 4^5(4|a|^2\cdot 4|b|^2\cdot 4|c|^2)\le 2^{16}\cdot \max(|a|,|b|,|c|)^6 \le \max(|a|,|b|,|c|)^7 $$
whenever $\max(|a|,|b|,|c|)\ge 2^{16}$.

If $\max(|a|,|b|,|c|) < 2^{16}$ then the output contains at most $16+3\cdot 2\cdot 16 = 112$ bits, so we can set $k=7$, $K=2^{112}$.